# workspace.Tool.Handle.Script6: invalid argument#3(Vector3 Expected, Got Instance)

Tags: roblox

I'm trying to make the part follow the mouse's Position Globally via remoteEvents. But i got this error

workspace.Tool.Handle.Script6: invalid argument#3(Vector3 Expected, Got Instance)

is there something wrong?

Local Script:

```
local tool = script.Parent.Parent
local rEvent = script.Parent.MoveToMousePos

tool.Equipped:Connect(function(mouse)
    mouse.Move:Connect(function()
    rEvent:FireServer(mouse.Hit.p)
end)
end)
```

Script:

```
local tool = script.Parent.Parent
local rEvent = script.Parent.MoveToMousePos
local part = workspace.Test


rEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(mousePos)
   part.Position = mousePos
end)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is telling you that assignment to `part.Position` is failing because the supplied value is not a Vector3, but is instead an [Instance](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Instance). So looking at how the `mousePos` variable is assigned is the clue to the problem.

Whenever a client fires a [RemoteEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/RemoteEvent), the [OnServerEvent](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/function/RemoteEvent/FireServer) supplies the [Player](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Player) instance that sent the message, and then all of the arguments. So currently, the mouse position *is* being sent up to the server Script, but it is being ignored in the function signature, and the `mousePos` variable is being assigned as the Player that called `RemoteEvent.FireServer()`.

To fix your code, just add a variable to account for the player that called the RemoteEvent.

```
rEvent.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player, mousePos)
    part.Position = mousePos
end)
```